# Limiting redrive from AWS DLQ

Tags: amazon-sqs

I have SQS->Lambda set up with SQS attached to DLQ with proper redrive policy based on maxReceiveCount. I would like to redrive failed messages from DLQ to source queue for three times after some interval. I know DLQ supports redrive to SQS but Is there any way to limit the redrive to some specific times? One option I can think is triggering a lambda scheduler and poll messages from DLQ and send to the source SQS after validating some custom header attached (like maxAttempts).

Answer (score 0):

I think it's better to define `maxReceiveCount` as 3 in your queue and then move the failed messages to DLQ if max receive count exceeds 3. Now you don't need to redrive them to source queue.

Then you can analyse the failed messages in DLQ if necessary without any additional integrations to restrict moving them to source queue. If required, you can decide to redrive them or not.

Comment: yea, I define maxReceiveCount as 3 so it will get landed in DLQ after three failure attempts. Now I want to redrive them back to source queue again after say 3 hrs just to try once again after an interval

Comment: Then I think having a lambda scheduled to run every 3 hrs to re-drive DLQ failed messages back to source queue will be the way to go.